# My application was rejected due to bugs in my app when reviewed on iPad running iOS 13.1.2 on Wi-Fi

Tags: cordova

I have tested the application on my iPhone X".

After being rejected once, I checked my app on all available xcode simulators working properly.

However, my app was again rejected due to "No content / suggestions loaded".

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to see the full rejection comment.

Comment: We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPad and iPhone running iOS 13.1.2 on Wi-Fi.

We were not able to fully load your app content after launch.

Comment: This message that I received from app store without  any further clarification